# Join two objects by key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I stuck on mergin 2 objects into one. Let's say I have 2 arrays of objects:
One is childs:

```
let childsWithMoreInfo = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'somename',
  parent: {
    id: 2
  },
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'some child name',
  parent: {
    id: 4
  }
}];
```

And the second one is Parents:

```
let parents = [{
  id: 1,
  parentName: 'The first',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 2,
  parentName: 'The second',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 3,
  parentName: 'The third',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 4,
  parentName: 'The fourth',
  child: {}
}];
```

And I would to merge these objects like this:

```
        let combined = [
            {
                id: 1,
                parentName: The first,
                child: {}
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                parentName: The second,
                child: {
                    id: 1,
                    name: somename,
                }
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                parentName: The third,
                child: {}
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                parentName: The fourth,
                child: {
                    id: 2
                    name: some child name,
                }
            },

        ]
        ];
```

So basically it should be something like:
 `let combinedList = parents.child = childsWithMoreInfo where parents.id = childsWithMoreInfo.parent.id` . On which method I should take a look? Do you have any ideas how can easily achieve that?

Comment: They are merged into child.

Comment: I recommend you to look into lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4. They have all sorts of functions that merges arrays on different conditions. You could of course build a merger yourself with a loop in a loop.

Comment: @crotoan Re-read Question.

Comment: I already looked at it multiple times, but have no idea which method I can use :(

Answer (score 1):

I really know how to use forEach, I wanted to avoid it.

This is what I made:

```
    this.combined = _.map(parents, (parent) => {
            parent.child = childs.find(child => child.parent.id === parent.id);
        return parent;
    });
```

Thank you for all of your answers.

Comment: Why not a built-in JS array's `map`?

Comment: Any reason to prefer it over `Array.prototype.map`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate then with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for every object.

Then have a lookup in the map and assign the values to ch parent object.

```js
var childsWithMoreInfo = [{ id: 1, name: 'somename', parent: { id: 2 } }, { id: 2, name: 'some child name', parent: { id: 4 } }],
    parents = [{ id: 1, parentName: 'The first', child: {} }, { id: 2, parentName: 'The second', child: {} }, { id: 3, parentName: 'The third', child: {} }, { id: 4, parentName: 'The fourth', child: {} }],
    map = new Map;

parents.forEach(p => map.set(p.id, p));
childsWithMoreInfo.forEach(c => {
    var o = map.get(c.parent.id);
    o.child = { id: c.id, name: c.name };
});
console.log(parents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution would be the use of [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var childsWithMoreInfo = [{ id: 1, name: 'somename', parent: { id: 2 } }, { id: 2, name: 'some child name', parent: { id: 4 } }],
    parents = [{ id: 1, parentName: 'The first', child: {} }, { id: 2, parentName: 'The second', child: {} }, { id: 3, parentName: 'The third', child: {} }, { id: 4, parentName: 'The fourth', child: {} }];

childsWithMoreInfo.forEach(c => {
    var o = parents.find(p => p.id === c.parent.id);
    o.child = { id: c.id, name: c.name };
});
console.log(parents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Any performance improvements using a Map compared to iterating on JSON array using for/forEach?

Comment: map has o(1), but you could use find instead.

Comment: @AniketSinha it's not a "json array" but just a javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

Following code has some pure functions to do your task. I have formatted/cleaned the input objects also:

```js
'use strict';

let childsWithMoreInfo = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'somename',
  parent: {
    id: 2
  },
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'some child name',
  parent: {
    id: 4
  }
}];

let parents = [{
  id: 1,
  parentName: 'The first',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 2,
  parentName: 'The second',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 3,
  parentName: 'The third',
  child: {}
}, {
  id: 4,
  parentName: 'The fourth',
  child: {}
}];

function makeObjectFromArray(arr) {
  let obj = {};
  arr.map(function(item) {
    if (obj[item.id] === undefined) {
      obj[item.id] = item
    }
  })
  return obj;
}

function toArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key]
  });
}

function sampleParentChildren(parent, children) {
  let Parent = {};
  if (parent.constructor === Array) {
    Parent = makeObjectFromArray(parent);
  } else {
    Parent = Object.assign({}, parent)
  }
  children.map(function(child) {
    if (Parent[child.parent.id] !== undefined) {
      if (Parent[child.parent.id].child === undefined) {
        Parent[child.parent.id].child = {};
      }
      Parent[child.parent.id].child[child.id] = child
    }

  });
  return Parent;
}
let resampledData = sampleParentChildren(parents, childsWithMoreInfo);
console.log(resampledData, toArray(resampledData));
```

Answer (score 0):

To join the arrays in ES6, you can use the spread operator to join the arrays and just use plain old `forEach` to deduping. The spread operator is more declarative than Es5's array concatenation methods as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on MDN

```
[...parents, ...childsWithMoreInfo]
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let childsWithMoreInfo = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'somename',
    parent: {
      id: 2
    },
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'some child name',
    parent: {
      id: 4
    }
  }],
  parents = [{
      id: 1,
      parentName: 'The first',
      child: {}
    }, {
      id: 2,
      parentName: 'The second',
      child: {}
    }, {
      id: 3,
      parentName: 'The third',
      child: {}
    }, {
      id: 4,
      parentName: 'The fourth',
      child: {}
    },

  ];

var conjoined = [...parents, ...childsWithMoreInfo];

conjoined.forEach(function(parentConjoinee, parentIndex) {
  conjoined.forEach(function(childConjoinee, childIndex) {
    if (parentConjoinee.id === childConjoinee.id && parentIndex !== childIndex) {
      conjoined.splice(childIndex, 1);
    }
  });
});

console.log(conjoined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `for` loops, `break`

```js
var childsWithMoreInfo = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "somename",
  parent: {
    id: 2
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "some child name",
  parent: {
    id: 4
  }
}];

var parents = [{
    id: 1,
    parentName: "The first",
    child: {}
  }, {
    id: 2,
    parentName: "The second",
    child: {}
  }, {
    id: 3,
    parentName: "The third",
    child: {}
  }, {
    id: 4,
    parentName: "The fourth",
    child: {}
  }

];
let combined = [];
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < childsWithMoreInfo.length; j++) {
    if (childsWithMoreInfo[j].parent.id === parents[i].id) {
      parents[i].child.id = childsWithMoreInfo[j].id;
      parents[i].child.name = childsWithMoreInfo[j].name;
      break;
    }
  }
  combined.push(parents[i])
};

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: I would have gone with the same approach, as it's simpler, unless someone proves the performance improvements using map.